# Issue with xss-sanitizer plugin in grails 3.3.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, grails, grails-3.3

I am using grails-xss-sanitizer in my grails application in v3.2.11. When I tried to upgrade my application to the latest 3.3.4. It reported below issue:

> [2018-04-11 11:16:37,627] [main]   ERROR o.s.b.SpringApplication -
>   Application startup failed java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/FilterRegistrationBean
>           at grails.plugin.xss.sanitizer.XssSanitizerGrailsPlugin$_doWithSpring_closure1.doCall(XssSanitizerGrailsPlugin.groovy:38)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
>           at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
>           at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:418)
>           at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
>           at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:759)
>           at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:588)
>           at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:531)
>           at org.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithRuntimeConfiguration(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:559)
>           at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doRuntimeConfiguration(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:167)
>           at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:171)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:122)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>           at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:84)
>           at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:393)
>           at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:380)
>           at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>           at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
>           at com.the41.fraudnet.Application.main(Application.groovy:28) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           ... 34 common frames omitted
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
>
>   > Process 'command '/opt/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I saw in grails 3.3.x upgrade notes:

Spring Boot 1.5.x - supported in grails 3.3.x

> Spring Boot 1.5.x removes a number of deprecated classes, notably
>   several of the classes within the
>   org.springframework.boot.context.embedded package.
>
> If your application is referencing any of the classes within this
>   package you will need to alter your imports to use
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet instead.
>
> All classes in the org.springframework.boot.context.web package have
>   been deprecated and relocated per the Spring Boot 1.4 Release Notes.

And xss-sanitizer plugin is using the classes defined in package "org.springframework.boot.context.embedded"

So, Is there any plans on the upgrade of xss-sanitizer plugin for grails 3.3.x or any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Is your question, how to make it work regardless?  Why don't you ask the the author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reasonable workaround to this other than to upgrade the plugin.

It appears that the plugin is being upgraded; see source here https://github.com/rpalcolea/grails-xss-sanitizer/blob/master/gradle.properties that references grails version 3.3.0.  You may also want to track or comment on this issue: https://github.com/rpalcolea/grails-xss-sanitizer/issues/1 since it describes the problem that you are seeing.